# Why does this matrix have norm smaller than 1?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $J_k$ be the $(k\times k)$-matrix
$$
J_k=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & & & & & 0\\
1 & 0 & & & & 0\\
 & 1 & 0 & & & &\\
 &   & \ddots & \ddots & &  &\\
 & & & \ddots &\ddots & \\
0 & & & &  1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
I guess this is a rather silly question, but it is said that
$$
\lVert J_k\rVert <1.
$$
I do not see that resp. do not know which norm is meant.

Comment: No, e.g. $\|J_k\|_{\infty}=\|J_k\|_{1}=1$.

Comment: When it is not specified, the $2-$norm is often, _though not necessarily_, meant. So that question can't be answered.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you don't mind I rename your matrix $A$, for notational laziness. :)

$$||A||=\max_{||x||=1}{||Ax||}$$

Now, for $x=\left(\begin{array}{c}x_1\\\vdots\\ x_k\end{array}\right)$, we have:
$$Ax=\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\x_2\\\vdots\\ x_k\end{array}\right),$$
Now comparing $||Ax||$ and $||x||$, or
$$||\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\x_2\\\vdots\\ x_k\end{array}\right)||\ \mbox{ and }\ ||\left(\begin{array}{c}x_1\\\vdots\\ x_k\end{array}\right)||,$$
it follows that $||Ax||\leq||x||$, such that 
$$||A||=\max_{||x||=1}{||Ax||}\leq\max_{||x||=1}{||x||}=1.$$

Note that whitout specifying which norm $||\cdot||$ is, we cannot arrive at $||A||<1$, but only at $||A||\leq1$, for example $||A||_1=1$.

Comment: Which norm is it? And since all norms are equivalent and, as Stef wrote, another norm is 1 - how does this fit together?

Comment: I cannot tell you which norm it is. The question should state that...